# Are there any tools similar to intellitrace

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellitrace

Do we have any alternative for intellitrace for visual studio 2012 professional version. It looks like Intellitrace is only available for Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version.

Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that IntelliTrace is available only with Visual Studio Ultimate.

Comment: just as a sidenote: what you are searching for is called a 'record-replay' reverse debugger. There are also 'real' reverse debuggers, but to my knowledge none for C#/Visual Studio. More informations over here -> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181527/why-is-reverse-debugging-rarely-used

Answer (score 4):

A few alternatives that I've used:

## [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview)

Just amazing.. if the UI doesn't put you off, and you don't mind waiting an extra few minutes for the traces to be viewable. It contains the most used features of intellitrace: Exception Stacks, Threads, Processes, File Access, Registery Access, Network Access.

There are a few more ETW Tracers and viewers: Microsoft Message Analyzer, Windows Performance Analyzer, ....

## [Stackify Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/)  or [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)

Very good for debugging problems with IIS. Runs on the server end as an IIS Http handler. Most used feature from these are: Application execution path, Exception stacks, request/response cycle with raw data.